# Add Solver Constraint For Non-Mutually Exclusive Ranges

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming

I use or-tools to optimize my fantasy baseball team. My setup very much resembles the program described [here](https://github.com/davehensley/fanduel-nba-optimizer/blob/master/nba-optimizer.py). The only difference in my particular case is that players can actually be eligible for a number of different positions. So, I end up with 1 player in a list for a specific position type, and the same player in another list for another position type. I am trying to avoid having the solver select the same player for multiple positions (which wouldn't be realistic).

Is there any way to modify the aforementioned program to constrain the use of a player to a single position even while they are technically eligible for many? Please let me know if I can clarify any further & thanks for your input.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add a “alldifferent” / “distinct” global constraint for the selected players

Comment: Yes, that would certainly do the trick. Not sure how or which flag (https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/linear_solver/pywraplp?hl=en) would enable the Solver function to do that.

Comment: There is an example of using "all different" in the OR-Tools "Getting Started": https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/queens

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but since I am using CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING I am getting an attribute error when I use solver.AddAllDifferent: AttributeError: 'Solver' object has no attribute 'AddAllDifferent'

Comment: The standard decomposition of an "alldifferent" global constraint is to use a domain encoding of the variable. This means for every variable and every value you create a 0/1 variable that takes the value 1 iff the variable takes that value. The idea for the "alldifferent" global constraint is then to constrain the sum of all 0/1 for the same value to be less or equal to 1

Comment: As an alternative you might want to look into using something like MiniZinc where you can express your problem in high-level constraints and your model is automatically decomposed for linear solvers. It also ships with the CBC solver by default.